# How can I view the items in the Spotlight cache?

Tags: spotlight

I'd like to view the data spotlight has imported.  Is this possible?

EDIT:  For example I can do this:

```
mdutil -svvv /Volumes/h8rdrive
```

and find out this volume was indexed.

I'd kind of like to find out what's *not* indexed though.

Comment: Er.  Everything is indexed unless you explicitly tell it not to be.  I think there are instances of external drives not being indexed by default, but I'd have to look it up.  I suppose you could put together some conditions and pass them to find.

Comment: @Harv - Uh... LOTS of the system stuff is not indexed.

Comment: @Fake Name - k, great.  Colour me corrected.  And submit a response, then.  :)

Comment: @Harv Spotlight indexes only "Everything within the scope of your permissions", but won't go to ~/Library/Cache or Preferences by default unless you activate "Other" in the config. Also, /System and such are *not* indexed. As for the OP's question, I'm not sure that there's a "Metadata" editor to read the index for a drive. But others may be more clever and come up with an answer.

Comment: You can force it to index everything.  Martín you were correct, it would have been better to use AIDE or tripwire.  It does make a pretty good uninstaller though.

Comment: By default, Spotlight indexes everything but Finder excludes system files from your searches.  There's a way to change this in a Finder search (there are optional search parameters to include system files and invisible files), or use `mdfind` (e.g. `mdfind -onlyin /System -name .framework`).  It also censors results to include only files you have permissions for; to see everything, search as root with `sudo mdfind`.

Answer (score 1):

[mdfind](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) is your friend here.

If you simply wanted a list of every file in your spotlight index you could do:

```
mdfind /
```

You can also get it to provide a count of the files.

```
mdfind -count /
```

On my system this returns 224353 which is a good reason not to run the first command!